# Identify which project is in runtime (Delphi Seattle)

Tags: delphi

I hope someone help me with this little issue...

I have two applications. Both of them use the same form shared added on DPR. I want to identify on a button click what project I am in runtime in this form.

Each one has a name, "projectA.exe" and "projectB.exe". But I can't get the exe name using "ExtractFileName(Application.ExeName)" for example cause the user can change it and the verification it will not work. I could get version of application but in some moment they can be the same too so this is not confiable either...

So, what is the best way to identify which project the button has been clicked independent of application name? Can I get the "project name" instead of application name in runtime, for example? Is there a way to do it?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why don't you want to use TApplication.name?

Comment: @TheBitman `Application.Nam` is blank - that inherits from `TComponent.Name` which since `TApplication` is not a design-time component, the `Name` is irrelevant. Unless you meant `ExeName` which OP already mentioned why.

Comment: @JerryDodge Not a design time component but you can modify it at runtime. If you add a unique name on startup in the dpr, then you can use it to display.

Comment: @TheBitman I still don't see that being any easier than just using conditionals.

Comment: `Application.Title` which is what shows up as the application's name on the Windows task bar. It defaults to the EXE name but is otherwise equal to the application title set in project properties.

Comment: There is no *project name* at runtime, because the project is only available at design time and is the name of the executable. Once the application has been built and the IDE closed, there is no longer any "project". Application.Title won't work, because that can be easily changed with SetWindowText(). You're out of luck unless you use a conditional define to identify the app. You can set this in your .dpr (project) file for each project, or in Project->Options->Directories and Conditionals in the IDE with the project open.

Comment: I haven't found what the difference between the two usages is. Maybe even a simple property in the shared form class is enough to solve the underlying problem.

Comment: Why do you need this information? How does it affect your shared form? Providing more information about the intended usage will helps us to provide better answer to you. Right now we are forced into guessing what do you need this for and therefore have no idea whether our answers would come helpful to you or not because in the end it all depends on what you do with this information.

Comment: @JerryDodge Your solution is the same as mine, just your "do something only for appX" is the place where you can perform the `application.name := AppX` and other operations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the version resource for your project you should define the program name. Presumably each of your programs have different names, and so this can be used to identify them.

Comment: I was going to mention that, but decided not to, because I believe it's one of the "dirty" solutions I mentioned in an earlier comment. Constants can also be used. Nonetheless, it does suit OP's requirements, so +1.

Comment: @jerry Given that you need to specify a proper version resource in many situations it has the benefit of specifying the information once and not having to duplicate it.

Comment: I though about that but it happens the same situation if I used conditionals, everytime I add this form for a new project, I'll have to make an "if" or "case" to specify the project. That's why I prefer (if it is possible) something that brings me automatically the name to not beeing necessary give maintenance all the time from now on... thanks for help ;)

Comment: No, you don't understand my answer at all it seems.

Comment: @David I read again your answer, it will probably gonne work. They have different names so, using "program name" or "original file name", even if the user change de application name, it has to work. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

This is the purpose of [conditionals](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Conditional_compilation_(Delphi)). In each project, you define a conditional, such as `APP_1` and `APP_2`.

```
{$DEFINE APP_1}
```

(Or you can define it in the project settings per build configuration)

Then this form can check which conditional is defined.

```
{$IFDEF APP_1}
  //Do something only for app 1...
{$ENDIF}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jerry.
I used a simple example but I didn't specify exactly why I want this. Sorry for that.

I know conditionals but I believe I can't use them because I could use this shared form in many many project so I don't think using conditionals for each project I add this form should be practical in a long-term.

That's why I was expecting some function could bring me automatically which project the button's been clicked instead of making any conditionals.

If you or someone else got another way to have it I appreciate. If not possible, I'll use the conditionals anyway

Comment: @SisMaster The only other ways I can think of are much more difficult, dirty, and not guaranteed to work 100%. This is the only solution I know of which is purposely meant for exactly what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much. I won't find any other, I'll use conditionals as you suggested